NameError: name 'r' is not defined | It is defined, and It works in one function but not the other
I keep on getting the error "NameError: name 'r' is not defined".Here is my code:
    import discord
    from discord import app_commands
    from discord.ext import commands
    import nest_asyncio
    r = None
    nest_asyncio.apply()
    intents = discord.Intents.all()
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/", intents = discord.Intents.all())
    @bot.tree.command(name="joinrole", description="Set the role ID when someone joins")
    @app_commands.describe(join_role = "Enter Role ID")
    async def join_role(interaction: discord.Interaction, join_role: str):
        global r
        await interaction.response.send_message(content="Set the join role ID to " + join_role + ". Note: If this doesn't work, your ID probably is invalid!", ephemeral=True)
        r = join_role

    @bot.tree.command(name="checkjoinrole", description="Shows the role ID when someone joins")
    async def check_join_role(interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message(content="The join role ID is " + str(r), ephemeral=True)


    @bot.event
    async def on_member_join(member):
        role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=str(r))
        await member.add_roles(role)

I tried everything I swear to god. I just want to make a customizable role on join for my server. Now it gives me the error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'"
I tried a lot. So I want to make a customizable role on join, so I'm trying to add commands to set the role ID, rather than setting it in the file itself. Don't worry about permissions I will add later.

So, where's that 'r' actually defined in your code?

@Headcrab its defined at the join_role command ("r = join_role")

@qloha In this context, that isn't really what is meant by "define". Your check_join_role and on_member_join functions depend on r being defined, but it's only defined once join_role is invoked. What happens if either of those two functions are called before join_role gets called? r will not be defined at that point in time.

Specifically, the suggestion is that you explicitly define r in the global scope, not within join_role. If you need to update r within join_role that's fine, but it seems it should have a default value before join_role is ever called.

I have the exact same thing as in my example, except I put r = None after imports

@qloha Please edit your question to include the complete error traceback, which shows the exact line of code that is raising an exception. If you do define r within the global scope, don't omit that from your code snippet.

You may want to read up on how global works in Python.  Variables defined outside of a function or class in a module are global to that module.  If you try to read access a var_name  in a function, and it hasn't been defined within the function scope, then the interpreter will look to the global scope.  Using global var_name within a function tells the interpreter that any following attempts to assign to var_name within that scope will assign to the global namespace instead of the local scope namespace.

It seems that you didn’t define r in the code. You need to set r = None before the definition of the methods. Then you should be able to access the param in the methods through global.
r = None

nest_asyncio.apply()
intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/", intents = discord.Intents.all())
@bot.tree.command(name="joinrole", description="Set the role ID when someone joins")
@app_commands.describe(join_role = "Enter Role ID")
async def join_role(interaction: discord.Interaction, join_role: str):
    global r
    await interaction.response.send_message(content="Set the join role ID to " + join_role + ". Note: If this doesn't work, your ID probably is invalid!", ephemeral=True)
    r = join_role


I did though?
async def join_role(interaction: discord.Interaction, join_role: str):
global r
await interaction.response.send_message(content="Set the join role ID to " + join_role + ". Note: If this doesn't work, your ID probably is invalid!", ephemeral=True)
r = join_role #<------- HERE

I tried what you said and it gave me this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

You need to define it before the methods. It should be like this: r = None then lower in the code async def join role:  ….

could you possibly give me an example with the code I already have?

Edited initial answer with the example

thats exactly what I have right now and it gives me the error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

@qloha Congratulations! You've solved your original problem. Now you have a completely separate problem.

fr tho what is going on aaaa

It seems that this is a new error which came up after initial one was fixed. I don't see from the snippet you provided anywhere you try to access 'id'  attribute. You need to provide more code or complete traceback of the error to move forward.

@qloha Does it work if you add if r is not None: at the beginning of every other function except join_role() in addition to what's suggested in this answer?

Heres the full error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 441, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "c:\users\user.spyder-py3\bot.py", line 100, in on_member_join
await member.add_roles(role)
File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\discord\member.py", line 1051, in add_roles
await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

the error was at user_id

Seems that you try to envoke the method add_roles with None value. You should set it to the right class/value to be able to run the code.
